# Using multiple sidekiq databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

Hey I am attempting to spawn a sidekiq worker that connects to a completely separate Redis database. I know with 3.0's connection pooling this is possible, and I have been able to successfully push a job onto the correct Redis DB, but the problem is the Sidekiq web UI is not showing these jobs in the queue (I have mounted a separate Rack app for this that points exclusively to the other Redis DB). The "Busy" tab in the admin interface also shows my sidekiq workers that I have pointed at this DB, with correct PIDs.

Here's my sidekiq.rb:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  if ENV['REDIS_DB'] == "2"
    config.redis = { :url => "redis://#{SIDEKIQ_HOST}:6379/2", :namespace => 'drip' }
  else
    config.redis = { :url => "redis://#{SIDEKIQ_HOST}:6379", :namespace => 'drip' }
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  if ENV['REDIS_DB'] == "2"
    config.redis = { :url => "redis://#{SIDEKIQ_HOST}:6379/2", :namespace => 'drip' }
  else
    config.redis = { :url => "redis://#{SIDEKIQ_HOST}:6379", :namespace => 'drip' }
  end
end
```

My use case is that I need to have fine grain control over the jobs that go into the second database, so I need the workers configured precisely so they are only using as many resources as I need them to. I only want the workers that are configured in this way to pick up these jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web UI cannot be mounted multiple times to point to multiple Redises in a single process.  You have to run multiple web processes with `REDIS_DB` set too.

Comment: Thanks Mike, figured out my problem. The problem actually was that the new ConnectionPool that I was creating was not creating a namespace. Once I specified the namespace in the ConnectionPool block, everything worked as expected. +1 for fantastic internal code documentation in sidekiq that made it easy to figure this one out.